# xquery multi if-else statement

Tags: xml, string, if-statement, xquery

Using xPath, I'm getting data from html field, this data can be in this format (including parentheses):

> ### DATA |||| symbols i'm using to explain my code
>
> (bornPlace, bornDate-DeathDate) |||| (str, A-B) = note that str may also contain '-'
>
> (bornPlace, bornDate) |||| (str, A)
>
> (bornPlace) |||| (str)
>
> (bornDate-DeathDate) |||| (A-B)
>
> (bornDate) |||| (A)
>
> Or completely empty

I'm trying to retrieve each element into separate variable using multiple if-else statements, but it seems that it doesnt like multi-line commands (I think so).

I already made a code wich is not working :-/ (it says expecting return, found else if ....)

```
let $temp1 := data(normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(//div/div[2]/h2/text(), '('), ')')))

if (contains($temp1,','))           (:   (str, A-B) or (str, A)   :)
then
    let $bornPlace := substring-before($temp1, ',')
    let $temp2 := substring-after($temp1, ',')

    if (contains($temp2,'-'))
    then
        let $bornDate := substring-before($temp2, '-')
        let $deathDate := substring-after($temp2, '-')
    else
        let $bornDate := $temp2
        let $deathDate := data('')

else if (contains($temp1,'-'))
    then                            (:   (s-t-r) or (A-B)   :)
        let $temp2 := normalize-space(substring-before($temp1, '-'))
        if (number($temp2)=$temp2)     (: it's a number :)
        then
            let $bornDate := temp2
            let $deathDate := normalize-space(substring-after($temp2, '-'))
            let $bornPlace := data('')
        else
            let $bornPlace := $temp1
            let $bornDate := data('')
            let $deathDate := data('')
    else                            (:   (str) or (A)   :)
        if (number($temp1)=$temp1)     (: it's a number :)
        then
            let $bornDate := temp1
            let $deathDate := data('')
            let $bornPlace := data('')
        else
            let $bornPlace := $temp1
            let $bornDate := data('')
            let $deathDate := data('')
```

Also if there's a more beautiful way to do that, i'll take it :D

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A let clause is not an expression. You need to change this kind of logic

```
if (contains($temp2,'-'))
    then
        let $bornDate := substring-before($temp2, '-')
        let $deathDate := substring-after($temp2, '-')
    else
        let $bornDate := $temp2
        let $deathDate := data('')
```

by this

```
let $hyphenated := contains($temp2, '-')
let $bornDate := if ($hyphenated) then substring-before($temp2, '-') else $temp2
let $deathDate := if ($hyphenated) then substring-after($temp2, '-') else ''
return ...
```

Though in this particular case I would be inclined to write:

```
let $tokens := tokenize($temp2, '-')
let $bornDate := $tokens[1]
let $deathDate := string($tokens[2])
return ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `let` clauses are followed by expressions (starting with `if`), which is not valid syntax - a `return` is missing to make it a complete `FLWOR` expression.

Also the variables are defined in inner scopes, and their binding won't reach the outer scopes, which is not very useful.

Though they easily get cryptic, this might be a case for regular expressions, e.g.

```
for $input in
(
    "Capetown, 10/04/1932-01/14/2002",
    "Taipeh, 05/31/1988",
    "Anchorage",
    "08/19/1918-07/02/1997",
    "12/22/1978"
)
let $bornPlace := replace($input, ",.*$|^[-0-9/]+$", "")
let $bornDate := replace($input, "^.*, |-[0-9/]+$|^[^0-9][^,]+$", "")
let $DeathDate := replace($input, "^.*[0-9]+-|^.*,[^-]*$|^[^,-]+$", "")
return <test input="{$input}" 
             bornPlace="{$bornPlace}" 
             bornDate="{$bornDate}" 
             DeathDate="{$DeathDate}"/>
```

For details, see the specification of [regular expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs) and the corresponding [XQuery functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#string.match).

Comment: Oh my, i'm so bad at regex xD... Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Can you please apply regex on my example? I'm desperate xD

Comment: You should get your desired result, when you use the three `let` clauses that I posted, replacing `$input` by `$temp1`, and dropping all of your code, except for `let $temp1 := ...`. If that does not work, please explain what goes wrong.